# Change BuildConfig for Instrumentation Tests only

Tags: android, android-instrumentation

Is it possible to change the fields in a `BuildConfig` for Instrumentation Tests only?

The current motivation behind this is that I want to point an app's urls to a different server (i.e. a local mock server) only for Instrumentation Tests. These urls are configured via `buildConfigField`s in the `build.gradle` for several flavors of the app.